# Unable to Install gvim/dependency in local directory without super user permission

Tags: linux, vim, gvim

Wanted to install gvim in the local drives as I don't have the root permission but it doesn't install the GUI version [i.e. GVIM] of it.

Steps Followed:

First I tried doing the ./configure process with just the --prefix to local directory and said no GUI related things are compiled. Then understood that by default GUI is disabled.

Next in the src/Makefile I enabled the GUI option to use the GTK2 version of the GUI and also updated the prefix to include local directory. Then downloaded some packages called "gtk-vim-syntax" which contained some .vim files related to gtk2, gtk3, gnome etc. added that path to $PATH. Then first tried running the below configure option

```
./configure --prefix=/home/installed --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gtk2
```

But still when I saw the configure terminal outputs it said no--enable-gui found, so no GUI enabled.

Then when checked online they said, you need to first install vim-common packages and either vim-gtk or vim-gnome and everyone provide the option of sudo apt-install etc etc. but since I am not the root user I am unable to install that way. Is there anyplace where I can find those package and install them locally before I try to ./configure in the vim folder ?

Or is there any other way I can install the gvim and all its dependent files in the local directory and not as root user ? Why can't they add some notes/info on how to install the dependencies locally as well in the README.

Kindly let me know if anyone had overcome this issue. Thanks in advance !

Update:

I do see the gtk-2 is installed in the following path /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0 but not sure why the ./configure isnt auto picking it.
Do I need to set any environment variable so that the ./configure picks it up ?

Comment: I think your `libgtk2.0-dev` not only `gtk-2.0` to build gvim

Comment: @Ôrel From where can I download the libgtl2.0-dev ? any git site ? or anything from python org ? I do see multiple flavors on some pkgs site but I esp needed for RHEL 7.

Comment: the development files for the GTK has 20 dependencies. So it can be a nightmare to get all it by hand.
what about build on a computer where you have the admin permission and use the binary on the other computer ?